# Layout problem when mixing tasks and enumitem

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate, enumitem, tasks

There seems to be a layout issue when attempting to incorporate a `tasks` environment directly within an `enumerate` environment, when no text is specified between the `\item` (enumerate) and the beginning of the `tasks`.

Is there a way to circumvent this issue without having to resort to the use of `\text{}` and a negative `\vspace*`?

Notice that the same thing happens without the use of the `enumitem` package. The `tasks` documentation states that one cannot nest two (or more) `tasks` environments, which is why I'm nesting a `tasks` within an `enumerate`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\def\sample{Boring and meaningless text that is long enough to show layout issues.}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Test A
      \begin{tasks}
        \task Subtest A-1
        \task Subtest A-2
      \end{tasks}
  \item % No text here, before the tasks. CAUSES LAYOUT ISSUE!!!
      \begin{tasks}
        \task Subtest B-1 \; \(\leftarrow\) \; \textbf{PROBLEM HERE!!!}
        \task Subtest B-2
        \task Subtest B-3
        \task Subtest B-4
        \task*(2) \sample \sample
        \task Subtest B-6
        \task Subtest B-7
        \task Subtest B-8
        \task Subtest B-9
        \task! \sample \sample \sample \sample
      \end{tasks}
  \item Test C
      \begin{tasks}(2)%  %% Use two columns instead of the default 3 defined above, for no reason
        \task Subtest C-1
        \task Subtest C-2
        \task Subtest C-3
        \task Subtest C-4
        \task Subtest C-5
      \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output showing the issue associated to the above code]

## EDIT - 2015-05-30

---

The reason why the negative `\vspace` isn't a practical idea is because when the layout is such that the problematic `\item` sits at the bottom of the page, it generates an abnormal page break.

Illustration:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\def\sample{Boring and meaningless text that is long enough to show layout issues.}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Test A
      \begin{tasks}
        \task Subtest A-1
        \task Subtest A-2
      \end{tasks}
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \sample
  \item \mbox{}\par\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parsep-\itemsep-\partopsep}% No text here, before the tasks. CAUSES LAYOUT ISSUE!!!
      \begin{tasks}(3)
        \task Subtest B-1 \; \(\leftarrow\) \; \textbf{PROBLEM HERE!!!}
        \task Subtest B-2
        \task Subtest B-3
        \task Subtest B-4
        \task*(2) \sample \sample
        \task Subtest B-6
        \task Subtest B-7
        \task Subtest B-8
        \task Subtest B-9
        \task! \sample \sample \sample \sample
      \end{tasks}
  \item Test C
      \begin{tasks}(2)%  %% Use two columns instead of the default 3 defined above, for no reason
        \task Subtest C-1
        \task Subtest C-2
        \task Subtest C-3
        \task Subtest C-4
        \task Subtest C-5
      \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output showing the issue associate to the above code (second block)]

Answer (score 2):

Just correct the space vertically after inserting a blank entry:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,tasks}

\begin{document}

\def\sample{Boring and meaningless text that is long enough to show layout issues.}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Test A
    \begin{tasks}
      \task Subtest A-1
      \task Subtest A-2
    \end{tasks}
  \item \mbox{} \par\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parsep-\itemsep-\partopsep}
    \begin{tasks}
      \task Subtest B-1 \qquad \textbf{No problem here.}
      \task Subtest B-2
      \task Subtest B-3
      \task Subtest B-4
      \task*(2) \sample \sample
      \task Subtest B-6
      \task Subtest B-7
      \task Subtest B-8
      \task Subtest B-9
      \task! \sample \sample \sample \sample
    \end{tasks}
  \item Test C
    \begin{tasks}(2)%  %% Use two columns instead of the default 3 defined above, for no reason
      \task Subtest C-1
      \task Subtest C-2
      \task Subtest C-3
      \task Subtest C-4
      \task Subtest C-5
    \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Please see my updated question above related to the use of the negative `\vspace`. Any ideas to circumvent this problem?

Comment: For the moment, using `\mbox{}\par\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parsep-\itemsep-\partopsep-0.1mm}` (notice the extra `-0.1mm`) seems to resolve the abnormal page break without any obvious consequences. It is, of course, a less than optimal temporary hack...